# Using Future throws `Scheduler: nothing left to resume so we are exiting`

Tags: iolanguage

I'm playing with Futures in Io. I have some methods that do some work:

```
a := method(10 + 20)
b := method(20 + 30)
c := method(30 + 40)
```

And I want to run them concurrently. This works as expected:

```
m := method(list(@a, @b, @c))

f := @m
writeln((f join(" + ")) .. " = " .. f sum)
```

However, moving the work of creating the string into method `m` does not work:

```
m := method(
    s := list(@a, @b, @c)
    ((s join(" + ")) .. " = " .. (s sum))
)

f := @m
writeln(f)
```

This raises `Scheduler: nothing left to resume so we are exiting`.

Why? What have I not understood?

Comment: This now sounds like it's a bug in Io itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the interactive interpreter. If you put your code in a file it should work fine.

Comment: Sadly not true.

`~/scrap $ io --version`


`Io Programming Language, v. 20140919`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question, but I believe that this error is independent of your problem since I encountered it doing much more simple work in the interpreter.

```
Io> 1 proto
==> 0
Io> 5 proto
==> 0
Io> 0 proto
==> 0
Scheduler: nothing left to resume so we are exiting
  ---------
  Coroutine callStack                  A4_Exception.io 244
  Coroutine backTraceString            A4_Exception.io 274
  Coroutine showStack                  A4_Exception.io 177
  Coroutine pause                      A4_Exception.io 286
```

Then I tried the command again and it worked fine:

```
╰─➤  io
Io 20110905
Io> 0 proto
==> 0
```

Comment: This just happened to me too - just some very simple stuff in the interpreter and then got the exact same message as you.

Answer (score -1):

In io source code dir:

1. `rm ./libs/iovm/source/IoVMInit.c`
2. open `./libs/iovm/io/A4_Exception.io` and
   uncomment this line
   `//Exception raise("Scheduler: nothing left to resume so we are exiting")`
3. rebuild and reinstall